add parameters to an Artisan cronjob
Sorry in advance, I’m an .net developer, so PhP is something I’m not really familiar with.
Our hosting provider only have the ability to run cronjobs through calling a webpage.
We have a cronjob that needs an argument "schedule:run".
I found the article on which this particular script is based on.
https://dev.to/obasekietinosa/deep-dive-into-the-laravel-artisan-file-3nge
While reading the documentation (https://peridot-php.github.io/docs/class-Symfony.Component.Console.Input.ArgvInput.html), I found out that you can pass arguments by declaring an own $input variable, like
$input = new ArgvInput($_SERVER['argv'])

Is my understanding correct if I add the argument to the array, that this should work?
$input = new ArgvInput($_SERVER['argv', 'schedule:run'])

So the call would be:
$status = $kernel->handle(
    #$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    $input = new ArgvInput($_SERVER['argv','schedule:run']),
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

Am I on the right track?
